# GetOpenFileName() Is Interfering With SFML

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, sfml

I create an OPENFILENAME:

```
OPENFILENAME ofn;   
char szFile[260];      
HWND hwnd = NULL;             

// Initialize OPENFILENAME
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
ofn.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)szFile;
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
ofn.lpstrFilter = L"PNG Files\0*.PNG*\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

std::string input;
if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
{
    input = CW2A(ofn.lpstrFile);
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
}
else
    errorHandle("Open Dialog Problem");
```

But then when I try to import something via SMFL it says "Error: Unable to open file.":

```
sf::Texture _cursor;
    if (!_cursor.loadFromFile("Resources/Metal_Norm.png"))
        errorHandle("-Cursor Texture Couldn't Load");
```

Not sure why this error is occurring if anyone has any possible answers I would appreciate it.

Comment: `char szFile[260]; ofn.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)szFile;` This is very wrong, and a buffer overflow waiting to happen. Using a typecast to make the code compile should have set off a red flag that you were doing something wrong. Change `char szFile[260];` to `WCHAR szFile[MAX_PATH+1];`, `ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);` to `ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;`, and get rid of the typecast. Or you can use `GetOpenFileNameA()` instead, and remove `CW2A()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GetOpenFileName` [changes the current directory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/11/12/10089878.aspx) as you navigate around in the browser.

There is a flag you can set, `OFN_NO­CHANGE­DIR` which was supposed to prevent this but I notice the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839(v=vs.85).aspx) have been updated at some point to say it doesn't work with `GetOpenFileName`.

You could try that but if it's true it doesn't work, the solution would be to save the current directory (use `GetCurrentDirectory`) before calling `GetOpenFileName` and then restore it afterwards using `SetCurrentDirectory`.

Comment: Wow! You are an awesome human being, I just tested your theory and for the love of God it worked. Thank you, you are a life saver I would have never figure that out.

Comment: What you really need to do is stop using the working dir in a gui app. It is not predictable. No reason at all that it should be the directory containing the exe file.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I have never seen `OFN_NO­CHANGE­DIR` not work. And it does the same as your workaround. It does not prevent the CWD from changing while navigating. It restores the original CWD before the dialog closes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: What, you mean MSDN is wrong about something? Heavens to betsy! ;)

Answer (score 0):

**What I did to fix this problem with the help of *Jonathan Potter*:**

1.) Saved the current directory of the SFML application.

```
LPCWSTR mainDirectory = GetCurrentD();
```

2.) Did what I had to do with the GetOpenFileName() function.

```
Tilemap t(file.GetWindowWidth(), file.GetWindowHeight(), file.GetTileWidth(), file.GetTileHeight(), file.GetScale(), file.GetTop(), OpenFile());
```

3.) Then restored the directory back to the original starting directory I had saved.

```
if (!SetCurrentDirectory(mainDirectory))
    errorHandle(L"Didn't Set Directory");
```